# in UNIX shell the difference between a compound statement ";" and "&&"

Tags: bash

Say I want to touch mickymouse in /tmp

I can do

```
cd /tmp ; touch mickymouse
```

or I can do

```
cd /tmp && touch mickymouse
```

I'm not clear what the subtle (or less subtle) differences are between the two statements.

Would appreciate comments on the difference between the two.

Thanks.

Comment: @skjaidev, seriously you think I did no research ?!?. I tried to keep the question as brief as possible and looked to see if there were other similar questions and have been using UNIX for over a decade. Just one of those things that didn't pop out to me.

Comment: Yes I do think you didn't do any research. Here is a quote from the bash man page `command1 && command2: command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`;` terminates the statement whereas `&&` is the logical AND.

```
cd /tmp ; touch mickymouse
```

In the above, even if `cd /tmp` failed, `touch mickymouse` will still be executed.

In the second one,

```
cd /tmp && touch mickymouse
```

Do `touch mickymouse` only if `cd /tmp` succeeded

Comment: In other words `cd /tmp ; touch mickeymouse` effectively means "`touch /tmp/mickeymouse` if /tmp exists and you have +x permissions on it, otherwise `touch ./mickeymouse`".

Answer (score 1):

See that `&&` is special operation where the RHS of && is always executed only when LHS of `&&` is true.

or only when `/tmp` is available, you will be able to `touch mickymouse`.

Whereas in the earlier case, it just returns an error as `/tmp` not available.

Or you can just do effectively as

```
touch /tmp/mickymouse
```